# How to Place/Draw a rectangle in a panel in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I want to *place* a rectangle of a specified color at a certain location, as well as have said rectangle scale dynamically along with the panel

Right here I have a "view panel" inside my window, and on it, I want to place rectangles.
I have tried creating panels and setting their background color to mimic a rectangle, but I can't really set their height as preferred.

```
wxBoxSizer* viewPanelSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);



wxPanel* red_rectangle = new wxPanel(viewPanel, wxID_ANY, wxPoint(0, 0), wxSize(20, 100));
red_rectangle->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(255, 0, 0));

wxPanel* green_rectangle = new wxPanel(viewPanel, wxID_ANY, wxPoint(0, 0), wxSize(20, 100));
green_rectangle->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(0, 255, 0));

viewPanelSizer->Add(red_rectangle, 0, wxEXPAND | wxALL);
viewPanelSizer->Add(green_rectangle, 0, wxEXPAND | wxALL);


viewPanel->SetSizerAndFit(viewPanelSizer);
```

**I have also heard about wxRect**

```
wxRect* blue_rectangle = new wxRect(0, 0, 20, 100);
```

**but I dont see it on screen? and how would I fill it with color?**

Comment: you should catch EVT_PAINT event for the panel and draw a rectangle with `dc.DrawRectangle()`. Check the documentation for the parameters.